Banno Widget showing auth error even though the token is valid
enter image description here
enter image description here
We are experiencing an issue when a Banno FI loads our app within the widget. The first screenshot shows our app, but I’ve also noticed the same issue in another app loaded in the widget. When we switch to standalone mode (by opening the app in a new tab), it loads correctly.
This issue seems to occur on Edge browser, but we don’t see it on the mobile app. We’re not sure if it relates to how we’re logging into the FI. Here are the steps:
•   Enter username and password
•   Provide OTP
•   Login

I can provide more info if needed
After successfully logging in, we should be able to see our app loaded in any browser without seeing any errors

You'll definitely want to make sure to double-check the Browser and OS Support Policy for Banno, as that applies to the Banno Digital Toolkit (such as plugins). In this case, it's a bit difficult to tell precisely which version of Microsoft Edge is at issue.

Looks like those two different x-request-ids (one for the "Buy Now Pay Later" plugin and one for the "Zogo" plugin) have an HTTP 400 Bad Request response which states that the "authorization request has expired". That might hint at a session timeout or similar.
